# HTML5 Canvas and hiding lower layers

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a app that shows coloured dots moving across the screen, following set routes. There is a save button the saves the current screen to a .png format.

The problem I am having is that if I click the save image button several times the images don't just show the current position of that click, they show all previous positions from when the save button was clicked.
E.g. if at click 1 the dot is as position 1 and click 2 it is at position 2. Image two will show positions 1 and 2. A third image would show positions 1,2 and 3.

Obviously there is an issue with layering or not clearing the canvas but I can't see the problem.

the save code (wrapped in an AngularJS app) is :

```
$scope.saveImage = function() {

                var stageWidth = jQuery("#mainStage").width();
                var stageHeight = jQuery("#mainStage").height();
                var html = d3.select("#mainStage")
                        .attr("version", 1.1)
                        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
                        .attr("width",stageWidth)
                        .attr("height",stageHeight)
                        .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

                var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(html);
                jQuery("#canvas").height(stageHeight);
                jQuery("#canvas").width(stageWidth);

                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var context = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext("2d");

                var image = new Image;
                image.src = imgsrc;
                image.onload = function() {

                    context.drawImage(image,0,0);
                    var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                    var pngimg = '<img src="' + canvasdata + '">';

                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    console.log(a);
                    a.download = "sample.png";
                    a.href = canvasdata;
                    a.click();
                };

            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you clear the canvas between the drawing-loops? I'm guessing you clear it instead of filling the background with a color. I think you'll get the correct result if you do `ctx.fillRect()` between each drawing-loop. To solve the layering problem, you need to detect which variable that has the previous data caches, and clear it each time a new image is saved.

Answer (score 0):

This would mean that it has not been through the digest loop. A common problem with mixing jQuery and AngularJs. Add a watcher.

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?